# Insert HTML into CSV programmatically in Java or Scala

Tags: java, html, excel, scala, csv

I am looking to create a simple 3 column csv file programmatically representing an email. Essentially, each row in the csv file will contain 3 columns:

1. email address
2. subject line
3. html content / body of the email

I am looking to do with this with Java / Scala. The problem I am running into is I can't seem to get it to fit in 3 columns, because of formatting. I have done what I could to save it as a simple 1 line string (see below), but I am wondering if maybe it is a limitation of csv / excel files in general, because I can't even manually store the html into a single cell.

Does anybody know if this is possible? I would like to retain all the formatting if possible, because on the receiving end this will be parsed and used for sending a real email.

Thank you all in advance.

```
Sample Scala Script:
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env scalas
!#

import java.io.FileWriterenter    
import java.io.IOException    
import scala.xml.Utility

val emailAddress = "abc123@gmail.com"    
val subjectLine = "New Sales Are Live, Check It Out..."     
val body = scala.io.Source.fromFile("sample_email.html").mkString     
val writer = new FileWriter("output.csv")      

(0 to 10).foreach { _ =>       
writer.append(emailAddress).append(",")       
        .append(subjectLine).append(",")      
            .append(body).append("\n")      
}       

writer.flush()      
writer.close()
```

Comment: You're going to need to escape the string and remove all new line characters to make it work. You should do a quick search for parsers, there are at lot of open source options that will do the bulk of the work for you. I'd also question your rationale for storing it this way, it might make more sense to use XML in a case like this (CDATA sections), it seems like you're asking for a lot of trouble for not a lot of payoff.

Comment: CSV is a little more complicated than just comma-delimiting a list: How do you escape commas and newlines? If you quote the values, how do you escape the quotes? You'd probably be better off using an existing CSV library than trying to implement your own. But like Daniel said, CSV doesn't seem appropriate for this kind of data anyway...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. I actually would prefer not to use CSV, but the receiver of this data requires it in CSV format unfortunately. I will look into a csv library. Below someone recommended opencsv, will start there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just like others I would recommend using one of the existing csv libraries to properly escape all kinds of characters. Here is one of them: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

SBT dependency:

```
"net.sf.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "2.3"
```

Or just download a jar since you have a shell script and put it on classpath.

You can use it in this way:

```
val os = ...OutputStream...
val w = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"))
w.writeAll // or: w.writeNext ... etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I almost have it working now, although now it appears to be converting semicolons to "," (quote/comma/quote). For example, it converts ".navDate a {color:#9e9e9e; text-decoration:none;}" into ".navDate a {color:#9e9e9e"," text-decoration:none","}"